# My existing Django project is being required by other unrelated Django projects (both newly-created and existing)

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Hi I wanna ask about this strange behavior I've discovered just now in my PC when running a newly-created Django project.

I have an existing and ongoing Django project `pgadn_website` (created 2 mos. ago) which has its own virtual env,

and just now I've created a fresh Django project called `Blog` which I intend to use for testing some stuff which also has its own virtual env.

So strange that when I execute runserver on `Blog`, it gives me this error:
[image]

I'm suspecting I might have set something globally but I don't know where to look for it.

**P.S.**

`pgadn_website` project is running just fine,

but the error above happens on pretty much *every new project* I create AND on all *existing projects* that were created *before* the `pgadn_website` project.

Comment: However, you probably have a DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable set.

Comment: Gotcha! Totally forgot about it but 2 months ago I did set that env variable. I removed it and everything is good now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the comment by @DanielRoseman above, removing the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE from my env variables did fix the problem. Thanks!